# Axios Node Put com autenticação não acessa

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Fiz uma aplicação node (v12.14.1) para acessar um webService. O mesmo possui Basic Autentication.

```
const uname = "xxxxxxxxx";
const pass = "%$7675845353525$%";    
const p_cpf = "97856353424";
const p_senha =  "xxx1111";  
const myurl = "https://defesaagropecuaria.sp.gov.br/api/servicos/login";

const updateUser = async () => {
  try {
      const res = await axios.put(myurl, {
          cpf: p_cpf,
          senha: p_senha,
          auth: {
            username: uname,
            password: pass
          }
      });
      console.log(res.data.token);
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Ao executa ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Error: write EPROTO 5300:error:1425F102:SSL
>   routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported
>   protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1929:

O que pode estar ocorrendo? Pelo que pesquisei isso está relacionado a versão mínima do Node, porém não consegui descobrir como setar isso no meu código. Gostaria de saber também se está correta a forma em que estou passando os parâmetros (ele solicita o cpf e a senha do usuário e a *Basic autentication*)

Comment: Tenta rodar seu `node` com o argumento `--tls-min-v1.0`

Answer (score 0):

Ao que tudo indica o servidor que você está tentando acessar usa uma versão TLS menor do que a suportada pela sua versão do `Node.js`. Desde a `v11.4.2` a versão TLS mínima é a [`TLSv1.2`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_default_min_version).

Para executar o seu código, tente iniciar o `Node.js` com o argumento `--tls-min-v1.0`.

No caso do seu segundo erro, basta utilizar a linha abaixo  antes do `axios.put`. Mas cuidado, esta alteração não é recomendada:

```
process.env.['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
```

---

> [`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_tls_reject_unauthorized_value)
>
> If value equals '0', certificate validation is disabled for TLS connections. This makes TLS, and HTTPS by extension, insecure. The use of this environment variable is strongly discouraged.

Em tradução livre:

> Se o valor for igual a '0', a validação do certificado será desativada para conexões TLS. Isso torna TLS e HTTPS por extensão inseguros. O uso dessa variável de ambiente é fortemente desencorajado.

Comment: Iniciei meu node assim: node proxy.js --tls-min-v1  (proxy.js nome do meu arquivo node), mas o erro persiste:
Error: write EPROTO 5736:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\statem_lib.c:1929:

Comment: Havia executado o comando de forma errada. Com a forma correta: node --tls-min-v1.0 proxy.js
agora tenho o seguinte erro:
Error: self signed certificate

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, acho que funciona, mas trata especificamente de certificados autoassinados. Não permite certificados expirados ou inválidos. Para permitir qualquer certificado, você deve adicionar esta linha na parte superior do seu código;

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

Isso permitirá praticamente qualquer coisa, mas também é perigoso, portanto, use com cuidado.